# SQL query that returns the value from one column which is duplicated but in other column has 1 null and one value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Important: Metabase SQL is READ only, this metabase is using a POSTGRESQL.

This is my table:

| Origin | Shipment | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchase.23 | shipment.42 | 356 | 2 |
|  | shipment.42 | 356 | 2 |
| Purchase.25 | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
|  | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
| Purchase.18 | shipment.427 | 666 | 4 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 4 |
| Purchase.20 | shipment.427 | 666 | 3 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 3 |
|  | shipment.427 | 677 | 3 |
|  | shipment.9999 | 222 | 9 |
|  | shipment.427 | 677 | 1 |
|  | shipment.9999 | 222 | 9 |
|  | shipment.1111 | 7 | 11 |
|  | shipment.1111 | 564 | 6 |
|  | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 4 |
|  | shipment.5555 | 756 | 1 |
| Purchase.22 | shipment.427 | 677 | 4 |
|  | shipment.4444 | 755 | 5 |
| Purchase.77 | shipment.3333 | 751 | 9 |

Notice in the table above, that Purchase.22 has 4 in Quantity and there are two shipments with the same shipment as the Purchase.22 row with 1 and 3 in quantity, both summed are the 4 of the Purchase.22 row.

The query should return this:

| Origin | Shipment | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchase.23 | shipment.42 | 356 | 2 |
|  | shipment.42 | 356 | 2 |
| Purchase.25 | shipment.422 | 256 | 12 |
|  | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
|  | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
|  | shipment.422 | 256 | 4 |
| Purchase.18 | shipment.427 | 666 | 8 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 4 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 4 |
| Purchase.20 | shipment.427 | 666 | 3 |
|  | shipment.427 | 666 | 3 |
| Purchase.22 | shipment.427 | 677 | 4 |
|  | shipment.427 | 677 | 3 |
|  | shipment.427 | 677 | 1 |

A little bit more of info, I'm working on a BI tool named Metabase, I'm a junior I just started a month ago and they gave me this stuff to do and the query I'm making is to know how many articles I have on the ivnentory. Unfortunately some articles are duplicated, if they were all duplciated I could easily divide the quantity by 2. But i's never easy. I have values that completly lack of origin and values that lack of shipment and both aren't coupled with other value that has both, and other products that are triplicated and have different quantitites, hence I cannot divide it that easily.

I tried to find any pattern with other columns form the table, but nothing worked at least on shipment.out while in other shipment values like shipment.out.return I found patterns that helped me without the necessity of using a SQL query.

Comment: First, why is there a NULL value?

Comment: Don't ask to provide different solutions for different tasks in the same post. If you are interested in having one further different output, create a new full post where you explain your situation, your new expected output, and make a reference to this post for further information.

Comment: How are we supposed to associate shipments with origins when those values are null? Are you assuming the rows are essentially arranged in that order?

Comment: I don't know if it is even possible. The rows are in a random order

Comment: There's no way to associate records that have NULL values in the "*origin*" field to their corresponding origin, because the DBMS stores records in a different order with respect to what you see here, you should have partitioning ids or something like that at least. This looks like a work that is better carried out in an excel spreadsheet rather than a database (you can't really do it in a db reliably).